LT3582-12 Not Putting Out +-12V (edit: downstream component is to blame)
We recently integrated the LT-3582-12 into a small PCBA and measured the output voltage.
The LT-3582-12 is not putting out the advertised range; here's what we're getting instead:
At 3.5VIN, we have +12.01V and -2.36V.
At 3.8VIN, we have +12.01V and -2.39V.
At 4.1VIN, we have +12.00V and -2.44V.
At 4.6VIN, we have +11.99V and -2.51V.
At 5.0VIN, we have +11.98V and -2.54V.
The board consumes less than 1 mA when the LT3582 is disabled, and about 250 mA while active.  The LT3582-12 feeds a dual rail op amp, an OPA2990IDSGR.  The Op Amp outputs have very light loads (just the feedback resistor network). The 250 mA draw while active is suspiciously high for such little load.
The voltage output is very clean, we do not hardly measure any noise or waviness on either positive or negative output.
Device behavior has been the same with all 3 boards tested.  We also do not see the device responding on the I2C port on any board, but this could be a separate issue with the MCU (one of which is able to modulate the I2C port, and two of which were unable to operate their I2C).
We followed layout and spacing recommendations, along with part numbers directly from the datasheet and example board, as closely as possible.  However, due to space constraints, we had to push everything closer together, as well as use a thinner PCB.
The PCB is 4 layers and 0.6mm thick.  The inner two layers are 1 Oz contiguous copper ground planes.  The outer layers are signal 1 Oz plated copper.  All active components are on the top layer with the LT3582-12; there are no components beneath the chip.
Recommended Schematic
(LT3582 Datasheet): https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3582512fb.pdf

Our Schematic

Op Amps (Load)

Actual Layout

Board

[Update 9/13/2024]
So I powered up the +-12V rails directly from a  power supply while disabling the LT3582-12.  Smoke came out of the board, and then the power draw dropped below 1 mA.  The DAC and MCU outputs appeared to be working normally.  The LT3582-12 was powered up again, this time the outputs measured a solid +-12V.  However, the dual Op Amp did not output any meaningful voltage.  Hence, the dual OPA2990 needs to be investigated.
Also, I must say there are two analog switches which are fed by the dual rail supply:

So either the Op Amp is bad or the switches are shorted out.  Something is shorting on the negative supply side.  Part orientation appears to match the layout, but I could be wrong.  The little Dot on the corner indicates pin 1, correct?  The little red marks are the required Pin 1 positions.

The negative rail output from the LT3582-12 is quite clean:


What is that asterisk (*) for in the footprint of D1? Did you mounted it with the cathode to the bottom of the picture (pin 3 and 4)?

@Rodo The cathodes are facing downward (as marked by the silkscreen).  You may tell the orientation by zooming in to the board image closely.  The * is some kind of documentation artifact from Fusion 360.

I noticed that there's I2C lines. By chance, have you looked at what the status registers tell you? That may be able to provide some hints.

Do you have a thermal camera to see where all the energy is going to?

@Jens Unfortunately I do not.  But I know the heat is coming up through the inductors, because they're warm to the touch.  The main LT3582 chip is the hottest chip while active.

@Colin None of the LT3582 chips seem to respond when we scan the I2C address.  This could be a microcontroller issue, but we will potentially attach an external logic analyzer just to make sure.

Can you disable the LT3582 and feed the OpAmp circuit with an external supply? Just to be sure the issue is not at the load side.

Can you post a scope shot of the negative switch node? (SWN)

The two 10 pin ICs right bottom look rotated with respect to the PCB printing.

@Jens Keen observation.  I double checked the orientation of the two bottom right ICs and they are indeed correct.

@Jens Your suggestion to isolate the load side was excellent.  The problem is no longer the LT3582 (at least not fully).  Rather, the load side is clamping the negative rail to Ground.

@JohnD With the faulty load removed, both the negative and positive rail outputs are very clean and flat.

The LT3582-12 is not at fault, the load is somehow overpowering the negative rail of the supply.  Thanks to @Jens for the suggestion.
Solution: Turns out, I had improperly connected the thermal pad of the op amp to Ground, instead of V- or left floating.  The Op Amp was shorting V- to ground through the thermal pad.  The solution was to cut the trace with a dremel, after which the op amp seemed to work a lot better.  The chips were not at fault, this was a design mistake.
When the load was driven by an external power supply, the board smoked, and then the load dropped to just a few milliamps.  When the LT3582-12 was powered back on, it was able to sustain +-12V easily.  However, the downstream OPA2990 was no longer amplifying the DAC signal at all.  Next step is to isolate the Op Amp from the output switches.
The output switches and control code were definitely working before a component shorted out.  Once the short occurred, the output switches are either shorting the Op Amp outputs to ground, to each other, or the Op Amp is ruined.
The "CTRL0" and "CTRL1" lines are not being driven together as verified by oscilloscope, so the signals are not being shorted together (at least programmatically).
Further isolation of the Analog Switches on another board reveals that the OPA2990IDSGR is to blame.  For some reason, this chip appears to be shorting the supply rails.  It is possible the chip was damaged during reflow, or the chips are simply bad.  However, being a Texas Instruments part, I would suspect the former rather than the latter.  We need to continue investigating the actual source of the issue.
The OPA2990 OUT0 signal is putting out the correctly amplified signal:

The negative (inverted / mirrored) signal (OUT1) is clipped to the strained negative power rail:


Are you sure you have the pinout correct on how you laid out the OPA2990 on your board? I've made that mistake before. Alternatively, there could have just been a solder bridge.

That's a good point @Hearth.  I double checked the pin layout for the OPA2990 with the 8-Pin WSON package, and the rails are indeed in the correct locations (at least on the design files).  It is possible that the PCB itself has some issues, such as shorted traces, or whatnot, but I do not know how to test this right now.  I do know that the OPA2990 does output an amplified signal corresponding with the rail input voltage when driven by the DAQ.  Which implies it is at least partially functional.

Well, @Hearth, you were right.  The thermal pad was connected to ground, which was a design mistake when the op amp is powered by a dual rail supply.  Should have been left floating or connected to V-.
